# Knative: Run service on specific machine type

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, knative-serving

I'd occasionally like to run a processing-heavy job on demand. Knative serving seemed like a good fit since it can scale from/to zero pods.

Is it possible to specify a node pool or node selector for a Knative service? Or is there some other way to ensure pods are created with specific machine types? I couldn't find anything in the docs.

I'm using GKE.

EDIT: **Open feature request (please upvote!)** https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/114402172

Comment: (Feel free to accept one of the answers below to close out this question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has moved to [this Knative issue](https://github.com/knative/serving/issues/1998), as the question doesn't seem to be GKE specific.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't currently possible to specify a node pool/selector while using knative, nor a way to ensure pods are created with a predefined machine type on knative.

I encourage you to file this as a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: Thanks! Is GKE the right issue tracker to add the feature request to?

Comment: Unless they have a category for knative, put in under GKE.